# Does git-svn handle moved files

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

Git doesn't explicitely track copied or moved files, but detect them for example with `git log --follow`. When using Git on an SVN Repo and pushing my changes with `git svn dcommit`, will SVN recognize those as copied files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git-svn` will properly reference the file history if it can detect the link at the time you `git svn dcommit`. If the only thing you do is move the file, it will work as expected and the SVN server will link file A to file B in its history.

However, if you also modify the file then squash the two commits before pushing them to SVN, then git may not properly guess that the file was renamed and you will get a deleted file and a newly created file with no apparent relationship in the SVN repository.

Answer (score 1):

You mean to get an entry in SVN Log like the following:

```
   A /xxxx/xyz (from /xxxx/zzzz.xxx:5555)
```

Yes you get such a thing.

Comment: Does the 'svn log' then show the copy source file history if used without "--stop-on-copy" ?

Comment: There shouldn't be a difference.